# php class as a plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How can I write a plugin that only intents to provide the class to be called by other plugins.
for example, if I have a class like this:

```
class Test{
     public static function testMethod(){}
}
```

then within wordpress envrionement, we will be able to call `Test::testMethod();`

Does the following works?

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: My Plugin
 ...other WP plugin headers
*/
add_action('init', 'test_init', 0);
function test_init(){
    $test=new Test();
}

class Test{
   public static function testMethod(){}  
}
?>
```

I don't think this is a right way to do it. any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't need the `add_action` - just activating the plug-in would cause WP to include the class, and a static function like that would then be available.