# Self referencing in a WordPress plugin class

Tags: wordpress, oop

Following the advice in this posting: [php class as a plugin in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668458/php-class-as-a-plugin-in-wordpress)

I've created a helper class for use with other plugins. In the class file, I have a declaration for activating the class, like:

```
function test_init() {

    $test = new Test();

} // End of test_init()
```

I'm able to access the functions in this class by doing something like:

```
Test::my_function();
```

However, I'm having issues referring to functions within this class from each other. For example:

```
function my_function() {

    Test::other_func();

}
```

In a case like this, I get the error message: "Function name must be a string"

I've tried $this->other_func, which returns the error: "there is not function "other_func" in the Class_Using_The_Test_Class.

I've tried self::other_func, which return the error: "Function name must be a string"

I tried using call_user_func() and I get: "call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback"

How do I call another function within this class?

Comment: You need to understand just very basic OOP to make this work, learning it is well worth the time. Just look at some examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to **activate** the class. I'll give an example.

Let's say this code lives in `helper-class.php`:

```
<?php

class Helper_Class {

    // Note: those are double underscores before the word 'construct'.
    function __construct() {

        // initialize/call things here.
        $this->init(); // this is how you call class functions.
    }

    function init() {
        // do some monkey-business

        return;
    }

    // we'll call this function from our other class.
    function some_function() {
        // do the fancy whizbang.
    }
}

?>
```

Now, over in your other class file you could have **something like this:**

```
<?php

// give ourselves access to the helper class.
require_once 'helper-class.php';

class Main_Class {

    // Note: those are double underscores before the word 'construct'.
    function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    function init() {
        // classes can't be used until an object of that class is created.
        $helper_class_object = new Helper_Class;

        // now I can call functions in my helper class.
        $helper_class_object->some_function();

        return;
    }

}

?>
```

I hope this sheds a bit of light on your situation. Just ask if you'd like further clarification. :)

Comment: Thanks Spencer. This is how I started to do it, but WordPress won't activate the plugin if the Helper Class isn't activated. Eventually, I plan on releasing this helper class in the plugin directory, if anything, so I can update all my sites easily when I make changes.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by **WordPress won't activate the plugin**? Do you get a failure notice or the plugin just doesn't show up?

Comment: Weirdness. I just took out the activation from the Helper Class and WP will activate the plugin. Earlier, it would give me an error message before (something about it can't find the class or something).

Comment: The other complication I was having was I was using an array entry to determine which function to call. Like:

     $helper_class_object->$arrayodfata['functiontocall']();

As far as I can tell, changing that array item to its own variable resolved the "Function name must be a string" error:

    $functiontocall = $arrayodfata['functiontocall'];

    $helper_class_object->$functiontocall();

I'm not really sure why this makes a difference since they are both strings, but it works. Thanks again for your help.